# why i cannot update details in this form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

sorry for disturbing all of you..but can you help me with this...because i want to complete my work...i really do appreciate that..almost half day im doing this function..but i couldnt see whats its wrong..

this is page that display all details...this page name updatepernternak.php

> $idprofil = $_GET['idprofil']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
>   penternak WHERE id = '$idprofil'"); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
>
> ?>    
>   Untitled Document
>
> " method="post">
>   
>        
>       ID : 
>        
>         " />       
>       Nama : 
>         
>         " />    
>       No I/C : 
>         
>         "/>     
>       Alamat : 
>         
>         "/>   
>          
>        
>         
>         "/> 
>       
>        
>       Poskod : 
>         
>         "/>      No
>   Telefon Rumah: 
>         
>         "/> 
>           No Telefon Bimbit: 
>         
>         "/>     
>        E-mel: 
>         
>         "/>
>
> ```
> <tr>
> <td>Nama Projek : </td><td>
>   <label for="nmprojek"></label>
>   <input type="text" name="nmprojek" id="nmprojek" width="539" value="<?php echo $row['nprojek']; ?>"/></td></tr>   
>  <tr> <td>Lokasi : </td><td>
>   <label for="lokasi"></label>
>   <textarea name="lokasi" id="lokasi" width="539" col="30" row="6" ><?php echo $row['lokasi']; ?></textarea></td></tr> 
>    <tr> <td>Tahun Mula: </td><td>
>   <label for="tmula"></label>
>   <input type="text" name="tmula" id="tmula" width="539" value="<?php echo $row['tmula']; ?>" /></td></tr>  
>       </table>  <center> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Kemaskini" />  <input type="reset" />  </center>
> ```
>
> > 

then if i click update button i will go this page name updatepenternak1.php

> ?>    
>   Untitled Document
>
> <
>
> if($submit=="Kemaskini") {        $id = $_POST["id"];
>         $nama = $_POST["nama"];         $ic = $_POST["ic"];         $lorong1 = $_POST["lorong1"];       $lorong2 = $_POST["lorong2"];       $telrumah =
>   $_POST["telrumah"];       $henset = $_POST["telbimbit"];      $emel =
>   $_POST["emel"];       $lokasi = $_POST["lokasi"];         $tmula =
>   $_POST["tmula"];
>
> ```
>   $sql= "UPDATE penternak SET nama ='$nama',ic='$ic', lorong1='$lorong1', lorong2='$lorong2', telrumah='$telrumah',
> ```
>
> henset='$henset', emel='$emel', lokasi='$lokasi', tmula='$tmula',WHERE
>   id = '$id'";
>
> ```
>   $result = mysql_query($sql);        echo "<a href='searchEnt.php' target='parent'>BACK</a>";        }
> ```
>
> ?>

but i dont whats wrong because i doesnt update at all...can anyone please help me with this...thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, In update query You have added extra `,` before `WHERE` clause.

```
 $sql= "UPDATE penternak SET nama ='$nama',ic='$ic', lorong1='$lorong1', lorong2='$lorong2', telrumah='$telrumah',
        henset='$henset', emel='$emel', lokasi='$lokasi', tmula='$tmula' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: ahhhh...why i always make mistake that very stupid..hehe...btw thanks alot for helping me..it work...thank you so much...